# Why isn't my code producing an array of "-" with an "X" at the chosen column?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to start replacing arrays on this game board with new arrays that have a change in a chosen spot.

this is my blank game board, I know it is possible to create with a for loop, which i may do later, but this gives my brain a good referance.

```
var gameBoard = [
    ["-","-","-","-","-","-"],
    ["-","-","-","-","-","-"],
    ["-","-","-","-","-","-"],
    ["-","-","-","-","-","-"],
    ["-","-","-","-","-","-"],
    ["-","-","-","-","-","-"]
];
```

here is how the player chooses their spot

```
var playerChoiceRow = prompt("Please select row of attack. (0 though 5)")-("");
var playerChoiceColumn = prompt("Please select column of attack. (0 though 5)")-("");
```

this is the code that is malfunctioning, it just creates a 6 long array of "X"'s but i feel like the code is correct.

```
function attack(playerChoiceRow,playerChoiceColumn) {
    var array = [];
    for (i=0; i<gameBoard.length; i++){
        if (array[i] === playerChoiceColumn){
            array[i] = "X";
        } else {
            array[i] = "-";   
        }
    }
    console.log(array);
}

console.log(gameBoard);
attack();
```

Comment: @DaveNewton It was actually mentioned: *"it just creates a 6 long array of "X"'s"* and *"My goal is to start replacing arrays on this game board with new arrays that have a change in a chosen spot."*

Comment: Hrm, indeed. Missed it on the cel but not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

```
gameBoard[playerChoiceRow][playerChoiceColumn] = 'X';
```

As to what is wrong with your code: you're not treating your `gameBoard` as a two-dimensional array. To get yours working, you would need a nested loop: first loop over the rows and then loop over the columns.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping to use the static array/object created as a base and then just switch it to the nested for loop.  I'll just keep the static one for refernce as to what the loop has created

Comment: The overall product of what i am attempting to accomplish is a computer vs. player battleship style game in javascript arrays.  This is a project of mine so i'm not looking to copy off anyone.